# JQuery Autocomplete Source path to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete which is calling a php file.  Works great.  Here's the problem.

If I put the PHP file in the same directory as my web page or in a subdirectory, it works great.  Like this:

```
    $(function() {      
        $( "#location" ).autocomplete({
        source: "subdirectory/lookup.php",
        minLength: 2,
        });
    });
```

No problem with the above.  Problem is, I want to store lookup.php in a different directory up a level in a directory called search.

I've tried "../search/lookup.php" and "http://www.mydomain.com/search/lookup.php" and a bunch of different combinations, all to no avail.

I can't seem to connect to the php file unless it's in the same directory as the page or a subdirectory.  This really sucks because I want to use this in the header across many pages throughout my site.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `../` is looking down a directory..no reason full path won't work... try removing `www`. Also path shown in code should work. Inspect request in browser console to see what path is actually used

Comment: also could be htaccess issue causing redirect or permission issue you aren't expecting

Comment: ../ should work 100% of the time. It moves up a directory. Also, full path should work. This could be caused because the .autocomplete function is being used twice. Have you implemented two versions of .autocomplete on the same element? That could cause the ../ to fail. @charlietfl 's suggestion of inspecting browser request via Javascript console is worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a redirect to the lookup.php file. For example you put the file redirect.php in the directory where the file is with the autocomplete function. Type in it

```
<?php header('Location: ../search/lookup.php'); ?>
```

Then put the lookup.php in the directory ../search/lookup.php(you know what i am meaning, i hope)

Not the best way, but should works.